What does the _PROP signify in the data dictionaries for claims center, billing center, etc?
In the data dictionaries for Claims Center, Billing Center, etc. would anyone know what the suffix _PROP signifies? It is attached to several virtual properties, yet I am unfamiliar with what it means and am not readily seeing it in the documentation.
e.g.

Searching in the documentation online for _PROP shows some results for integrating distance / spatial calculations, yet there are ~4k attributes in this instance's data dictionary with that suffix.

